# GKE ingress is not working with WordPress deployment

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy Wordpress on GKE, everything is ok except the ingress, the ingress is not able to connect to backend service, showing " SOME BACKEND SERVICES ARE IN UNHEALTHY STATE"
I would be grateful if someone help me.

**Wordpress deployment yaml file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-deployment
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: wordpress
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/www/html
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: mysql-service
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
          value: wpuser
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          value: pass@123
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
          value: wpdb
        - name: WORDPRESS_DEBUG
          value: "1"
      volumes:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: wordpress-volumeclaim
```

**Service yaml file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  ports:
  - name: portname
    nodePort: 30100
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

**Ingress yaml file**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-address
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com 
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: wordpress-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

[Ingress GCP Consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV5l5.jpg)

[Ingress GCP Consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU8BI.jpg)

[GCP logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iirhc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to go to https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/healthChecks/ and then modify the health check for the wordpress backend. For example changing it from `/` to `/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg` solved the issue in my case. This is described in this post https://serverfault.com/questions/826719/how-to-create-a-url-in-a-wordpress-that-will-return-code-200.

Answer (score 0):

In your spec

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com 
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: wordpress-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

you accidentally have two different backends: one for "example.com" and one based on the path "/" for anything else.  Since you are not specifying a backend for the "example.com", Ingress uses the default backend, which will never return healthy.

My guess is that you don't actually want "example.com", so deleting it from the spec should solve your issue:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-address
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: wordpress-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

Comment: Hi Gari, thanks for the help, I reapplied the new ingress suggested by you, but I am still facing the same issue, I would like to clarify that I am facing this issue only with Wordpress deployment, I have deployed Nodejs and Java applications as well using the same ingress manifest, which works perfectly.